# Need four random values in a range which total unity

Tags: random, conditional

I need to generate four positive random values in the range [.1, .6] with (at most) two significant digits to the right of the decimal, and which sum to exactly 1. Here are three attempts that do not work.

```
x = {.15, .35, .1, .4}; While[Total[x] != 1, 
 x = Table[Round[RandomReal[{.1, .6}], .010], 4]];
x = {.25, .25, .25, .25}; While[Total[x] == 1, 
 x = Table[Round[RandomReal[{.1, .6}], .010], 4]];
NestWhileList[Total[x], 
  x = Table[Round[RandomReal[{.1, .6}], .010], 4], 
  Plus @@ x == 1][[1]]
```

Comment: Is the sequence `{0.10, 0.20, 0.20, 0.50}` considered different from `{0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.20}` ?  This has the consequence that the population of sequences to be sampled from differs depending on the answer to that question.  Your attempt at an answer suggests that the ordering is important (meaning `{0.10, 0.20, 0.20, 0.50}` is considered different from `{0.50, 0.20, 0.10, 0.20}` .

Comment: What do you mean by "at most two significant digits"?  Do you mean that all four numbers have to be exact integers when multiplied by 100?  Or can we generate numbers that have lots of "insignificant" numbers after the decimal place, so long as we round them off before reporting them?  (In which case the rounded answers will not always add to exactly 1?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Normalize](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normalize.html) to find a list of random values between 0.1 and 0.6, which are rounded to two decimal places, and that total to 1.

```
rr = 0;
While[Total[rr] != 1,
  rr = Round[Normalize[RandomReal[{.1, .6}, 4], Total], .01]]
```

The random values are returned as `rr`. For example:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
rr = 0;
While[Total[rr] != 1,
  rr = Round[Normalize[RandomReal[{.1, .6}, 4], Total], .01]]
{Total[rr], rr}
```

> `{1., {0.4, 0.27, 0.11, 0.22}}`

Comment: This solution doesn't guarantee that the numbers are in the [.1, .6] range.

Comment: It also doesn't guarantee that the numbers sum to 1 (due to the rounding).

Comment: I think this will work if you change `Total[rr] != 1` to `Total[rr] != 1 || Min[rr] < 0.1 || Max[rr] > 0.6.` (But it's not very efficient.)

Answer (score 10):

Because you have very tight constraints, the number of allowed points is not very large, so you can generate all of them and then sample.

```
list = Flatten[
  Table[If[10 <= (100 - i - j - k) <= 60, {i, j, k, 100 - i - j - k}/
     100., Nothing], {i, 10, 60}, {j, 10, 60}, {k, 10, 60}], 2]

Length@list
(* 38831 *)

RandomChoice[list]
(* {0.17, 0.14, 0.4, 0.29} *)

Total@%
(* 1. *)
```

Not very clever or very efficient method, but it does the job ...

Comment: +1 Brute force can work just fine!  And to counter a claim that has now been deleted:  a simple random sample from `list` does require the individual numbers to have a uniform distribution.  The probabilities decrease as the individual values go from 0.10 to 0.60.  And the resulting numbers in each position have the same marginal distribution in that `Sort[Tally[list[[All, 1]]]] == Sort[Tally[list[[All, 2]]]] == 
 Sort[Tally[list[[All, 3]]]] == Sort[Tally[list[[All, 4]]]]`.

Comment: This is just a bit faster (which would allow for "larger" ranges of numbers):  `list = Flatten[Table[{i, j, k, 100 - i - j - k}, {i, 10, 60}, {j, 10, Min[60, 100 - i - 20]}, {k, Max[10, 100 - i - j - 60], Min[60, 100 - i - j - 10]}], 2]/100.;`.

Comment: Building off of @martin's answer, `Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[100, {4}, Range[10, 60]]/100., 1]` generates the same list and is significantly faster.

Answer (score 5):

```
RandomSample[IntegerPartitions[100,{4},Range[10,60]]/100.,1]
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I would, however, add a permutation ``RandomSample@RandomChoice[IntegerPartitions[100, {4}, Range[10, 60]]/100.]`` so that all four numbers have equal distributions. Otherwise, the numbers in the list are sorted in descending order.

Comment: I agree that it is not entirely clear from the OP's question whether he just wants a _set_ of four numbers or a random 4D point. I just wanted to point out that, for example, your solution will never return a list ``{0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6}``.

Comment: Your solution also provides a different population to sample from than @Domen 's answer.  Your solution has 1,843 unique sequences which are sampled uniformly.  Domen's solution has 38,831 unique sequences which when sorted match your 1,843 sequences.  But those 1,843 sorted sequences occur unequal numbers of times in the population of 38,831 sequences so the simple random sample from the two candidate populations have different results (even if only the sorted order is considered).  So the population from which to sample needs to be specified.

Comment: @JimB:  Domen's list of 38,831 tuples can be generated from this list of 1,843 tuples via `Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[100,{4},Range[10,60]]/100., 1]`.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Very good!  Now the remaining question is "From which of the 2 populations should a simple random sample be drawn?"

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1]

list = {##, 1 - +##} & @@@ Round[RandomPoint[Simplex[3], 10], .01];

Grid[Prepend[{"4-tuple", "total"}][{#, Total@#} & /@ list ], 
 Dividers -> {False, {True, True, {False}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is unfortunately not a correct solution as some of the values do not lie in the desired range $[0.1, 0.6]$.

Comment: It is, however, a very interesting solution to the problem.  With the introduction of a helper function, call it ```InRange[aList_, lowLimit_, highLimit_] := 
 And @@ (lowLimit <= # <= highLimit & /@ aList)``` it is trivial to select more elements for list and then choose only those InRange.  ```Select[list, InRange[#, 0.1, 0.6] &]```  I hadn't known about Simplex before this answer so it was instructive.

Comment: @Domen, thank you (totally missed the range requirement).

Comment: Rather than using `Simplex[3]` in @kglr's answer...if you instead define a simplex in terms of points, such as `s = Simplex[{{0.1, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.6, 0.1, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.6, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.1, 0.6}}];` you can then call `RandomPoint` using `s` as the input.  Everything else in @kglr's answer will still hold, but it will preserve the constraint.

Comment: @JoshuaSchrier, I don't think this works. Sample a lot of points and then look at ``Histogram[Transpose@list]``. You can clearly see that the fourth number has a different distribution (which should not happen as the problem is invariant under permutation), and it even exceeds the upper limit $0.6$.

Comment: I see what you mean @Domen... I think you can add the additional constrains by defining an `ImplicitRegion`...see answer posted below

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone has yet tried `FindInstance`:

```
FindInstance[{a + b + c + d == 100 && 10 <= a <= 60 && 10 <= b <= 60 &&
10 <= c <= 60 && 10 <= d <= 60}, {a, b, c, d}, Integers, 2, 
RandomSeeding -> Round@(10^6 RandomReal[])]
```

If only 1 result is requested, then the result seems to always be {60,20,10,10}.  The RandomSeeding option is necessary to avoid repeats.  The result then gets divided by 100 to get the sig figs, I think.

Here we have 100 results, 97 of which were unique when I ran it:

```
results  = 
 0.01 {a, b, c, d} /. 
  FindInstance[{a + b + c + d == 100 && 10 <= a <= 60 && 
     10 <= b <= 60 && 10 <= c <= 60 && 10 <= d <= 60}, {a, b, c, d}, 
   Integers, 100, RandomSeeding -> Round@(10^6 RandomReal[])]
Short[Results]
(* {{0.5, 0.21, 0.19, 0.1}, {0.18, 0.13, 0.11, 0.58}, {0.11, 0.54, 0.18, \
0.17}, <<95>>, {0.17, 0.17, 0.11, 0.55}, {0.3, 0.13, 0.47, 0.1} *)
Sort /@ results // Union // Length
(* 97 *)
Total /@ results // Union
(* {1., 1., 1.} *)
```

The last result suggests to me that there might be some machine precision roundoff errors.

Comment: This solution unfortunately does not obey the constraint that the numbers should have _(at most) two significant digits_.

Comment: @domen I think my update addresses sig figs.

Answer (score 2):

You could use[`DirichletDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletDistribution.html)

For example:

```
rv = Select[{##, 1 - Total[{##}]} & @@@ 
    RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[{1, 1, 1, 1}], 100000], 
   Min[#] > 0.1 && Max[#] < 0.6 &];
```

Illustrating the truncated region alluded to in other posts for first three components:

```
Show[ListPointPlot3D[rv[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], 
  PlotRange -> Table[{0, 1}, 3]], 
 RegionPlot3D[x + y + z < 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1], Mesh -> None]]
Grid[{##, Total[{##}]} & @@@ rv[[1 ;; 10]], 
 Dividers -> {{{False}, True, False}, None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Building on @kglr's response—the way to do this is to incorporate some of the additional constraints into the definition of the region from which sampling occurs (it is a bit more complicated than a Simplex).  We can define a region where the 3 variables go over the appropriate range.  The implicit fourth variable means that the sum of the 3 cannot be less than 0.4 nor greater than 0.9 (i.e., the fourth variable also goes from 0.1 to 0.6)

```
h = ImplicitRegion[
   0.4 <= x1 + x2 + x3 <= 0.9,
   {{x1, 0.1, 0.6}, {x2, 0.1, 0.6}, {x3, 0.1, 0.6}}];


RegionPlot3D[h] (*take a look before we proceed*)
```

[image: the region]

Notice how this extra constraint cuts off some corners that would have been present in the simplex...

Now we can continue with @kglr's solution:

```
list = {##, 1 - +##} & @@@ Round[RandomPoint[h, 10], 0.01];

Grid[
 Prepend[{"4-tuple", "total"}][{#, Total@#} & /@ list], 
 Dividers -> {False, {True, True, {False}}}]
```

[image: table of results]

Comment: Nope, once again this does not work. Generate a large sample and check ``MinMax[list]``. It will give you ``{0.09, 0.61}``. I have a (gut) feeling that sampling _reals_ and then using ``Round`` just cannot give proper results.

Comment: All of the issues with the proposed solution occur in the 4th position (what @Domen mentions).  Take a look at `Sort[DeleteDuplicates[list[[All, 4]]]]`.  There's an article back in the 70's about only two-thirds of the table in articles should add up exactly to 100% when rounding (no matter how many decimals are used).  So if you see an article with lots of tables (of real numbers rather than integers with constraints), then if all tables sum exactly to 100%, something is fishy.  (I'll see if I can dig up that article - either in the American Statistician or the JASA.)

Comment: Yeah, is definitely a rounding error related to the last place, as @JimB says.  I suspect that you (@Domen) could just change the inequality bounds so that it rounds the way you desire...or do a little post-processing.

Comment: This would be the correct way to do it if the numbers were supposed to add to *exactly* 1 but be reported out to only two significant figures.  (Which honestly makes more sense to me than constraining the values to be exact integers when multiplied by 100, which seems to be how most folks have interpreted the question.)

Answer (score -2):

Strategy:

1. Offset the target value range by 0.1
2. Generate 4x random values in the range [0-1]
3. Rebase range based on sum of values generated
4. Rebase values to reflect offset (0.1) x4 values => 0.6
5. Round to 2 digits (excepting floating point error)

> Array(4).fill(0).map(X=>Math.random()).map((X,ii,A)=>0.1 +
> (Math.round((100*X/A.reduce((C,I)=>C+I, 0.0)*0.6)) /100))

I doubt if the distribution is truly random, but it might help, depending on the application.

Comment: That looks like Python code. This forum is for Wolfram Language related questions.

Answer (score -2):

If the four numbers are to add to 1, then only three of them can be 'random'.

```
 In[98]:= sim = {1, 1, 1};
          While[6/10 > Total[sim] || Total[sim] > 9/10, 
             sim = RandomReal[{1/10, 6/10}, 3, WorkingPrecision -> 2]
          ]

In[100]:= sim

Out[100]= {0.18, 0.37, 0.23}

In[101]:= res = Append[sim, 1 - Total[sim]]

Out[101]= {0.18, 0.37, 0.23, 0.22}

In[102]:= Total[res]

Out[102]= 1.0
```

Comment: Your statement about randomness is not really correct. Also, unfortunately your solution is not working properly as it can produce $0.09$.

Comment: Just to echo @Domen 's comment:  Yes, it is true that with the restriction that the 4 numbers sum to 1, knowing 3 of the numbers will tell you what the 4th number is.  But that doesn't mean that the 4th number doesn't come from some probability distribution.  You're mixing up a conditional event with an unconditional event.

Comment: @Domen please explain how?

Comment: @JimB but it is a conditional event, there is condition that all four numbers add up to 1. This does not mean that the 'fourth' number does not have a distribution...

Comment: All 4 are discrete random variables with the restriction that they sum to 1.  Those random variables are therefore not independent.  The random sample is taken from their joint distribution.  To say that "only three can be 'random'" does not make sense.  All are random variables.  If $X\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$ would you say that $Y=1-X$ means that only one of $X$ and $Y$ are random variables just because $X+Y=1$?  Maybe we're just using a different terminology (random variables vs "numbers being random"?

Comment: @JimB indeed, what I mean is that if three of those numbers are known, then the fourth one is determined by the condition. In that sense it is not 'random' anymore, but yes, it has a distribution. The original question was about how to simulate such 4 numbers, and not what their joint distribution is, and I do not claim my answer shows joint distribution. Clarification appreciated.

Comment: To sample the 4 numbers one needs to know the joint distribution (or be able to construct the joint distribution using a series of conditional distributions).  @domen 's and Martin's approach constructs the sample space and then assigns equal probabilities to all elements in the sample space.  Stating that one of numbers is known given the other 3 simply re-states the restriction and doesn't mean something isn't random.  At best, the statement "If the four numbers are to add to 1, then only three of them can be 'random'." doesn't add anything.

Comment: @JimB Does one really need to know the joint distribution of (, 1-) with ∼Bernoulli() to sample the vector? The simulation outcome of the second component is determined by the simulation of the first one. So going back to the original question - for a moment forgetting about range restrictions - if the first three simulation outcomes are {a,b,c}, then the fourth one is determined by 1-a-b-c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130102/discussion-between-jimb-and-gosia).